# Brownie doesn't import the downloaded files

Tags: solidity, brownie

I have checked various questions regarding Brownie compile. But mine is a little unique. I have some Japanese font which is not read properly by the Brownie compiler.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkRm.png)

```html
PS C:\Bharath\src\crypto\python\demos\boss\brow2\brownie_fund_me> brownie compile
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

865kiB [00:01, 509kiB/s]
WARNING: Unable to compile smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1 due to a UnicodeDecodeError - you may still be able to import sources from the package, but will be unable to load the package directly.

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.12
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

contracts/FundMe.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source "C:/Users/チEôェバラト！EharathTV��.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
^--------------------------------------------------------------------------^

contracts/FundMe.sol:6:1: ParserError: Source "C:/Users/チEôェバラト！EharathTV��.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
^------------------------------------------------------------------^

contracts/test/MockV3Aggregator.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "C:/Users/チEôェバラト！EharathTV��.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol";
```

Comment: Can you add you `brownie-config.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add them into your brownie-config.yaml?

It should look like this:

```
dependencies:
 - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.1
 - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
   remappings:
     - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.1'
     - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie contracts@1.1.1'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Comment: Also check if the version is right since you are using old version of the contracts and solidity.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue then i changed solidity version in FundMe.sol file
to pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
I hope this will help you as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There could be a possibility of typo in brownie-config.yml file. I had the same issue and I found that it was due to a misspelling.

```
dependencies:
  # the pattern is <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```